# What design pattern should I be using if I want to run my tests for different countries

Tags: java, selenium, design-patterns, selenium-webdriver

[image: DataSheet]

Hello,

I'm creating test methods where I has to pass the country, type of product and different combinations of addresses where I populated Billing and Company address

I have to test for 4 different countries and each country has their own unique flow. So I have separate PageObjects for the different countries.

For example `AUPageObject`, `FRPageObject`, and `CAPageObject` java class files.

But some the locators and validation messages are same for the different country flows. So I'm thinking I will create a super class where I can put all the common page objects in that superclass. Is that a good idea?

For example:

```
public USPageObject extends AllCountryPageObject {
}
```

I also have to test all the countries where they can purchase two different product type (a trial product or buy now product). The I have to test with different combination where I have the option to populate or not populate company address. Then with different credit card types.

What is best test design pattern that I should use? Should I create an overload constructor for example? Any suggestions would greatly help.

```
public methodName (newCountry(CountryName), newCardType(Card), boolean isCompanyPopulated, new productType(product))
{

}
```

Comment: Is the page structure different for different countries? My guess is that it is not. If that is the case, then you don't want different page objects for each country. You would have one page object per page and the script itself might be different per country if the flow is different.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you abstract your generic tests out into a separate class with a method for each generic test.  Then when going through the test you call generic test x which then would avoid duplication of generically redundant items.  You can always return a true/false depending on if the test passes or fails so that it shows up at the parent test level.

This way you can keep your page framework architecture in tact, but have one off generics that get reused by all tests in the framework regardless of the page structure.  Then import and call in tests as appropriate.  If that doesn't work please describe your framework a little more or clarify a more specific goal.

*Example*: Login test method.  Each test that starts at the base of the application has to login, so even if you login and navigate somewhere totally different the login test itself is written once and called from a bunch of tests as the first step.